# Exclude child element of parent with selenium or xPath Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am stacked at the code, tried many ways and cannot find the right answer yet.
This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="description">
    <p>Text1</p>

    <p>Text1</p>

    <div class="excluding-class">
        <ul>
            <li>list1</li>
            <li>list2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Selenium and I have to pull some data from HTML code which has 
`<div class="description">`. But the child `<div id="excluding-class">` is making me a problem so I want to exclude it by calling `driver.get_element_by_class_name` or `driver.get_element_by_xpath`

Working code should export but without using `<p>` or something else:

```
<div class="description">
    <p>Text1</p>

    <p>Text1</p>
</div<
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean exclude child element? Do you want to change page `HTML` source or just to get text from `p` elements? What output you want to get?

Comment: I don't want to change it, I want to get text from "description".In real html document there is no <p> tags. There is a lot of tags which include text.

Comment: Because later, I will use `.get_attribute('innerHTML')` to get source code. But I don't want that source to be `class="excluding-class`

Comment: Is it always <p> elements you want to retrieve data from? You could adjust your xpath accordingly -> `driver.get_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='description']/p")` and then loop into elements that match this xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only XPath 1.0 (the version most common in selenium webdrivers),  there is no way to get the parent element who's innerHTML attribute will have the specified child element excluded. However, if removing the child element from the DOM is okay with you, the following is possible:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('excluded-class').remove()")
driver.get_element_by_class_name("description").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: Remember that any elements with a class of "excluded-class" will no longer exist in the DOM until the page is revisited.